# C program stops working

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program in C. I am pretty fluent in Java but I don't know much C, I'm trying to learn the syntax. This program doesn't really have a goal I'm just learning to compare strings, print out stuff, learn how to work with arrays and so on. The program returns no errors or warning, and it runs fine, but after it finishes command prompt says the program has stopped working. Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void printVowlOrElse(char *name[5]){
int i;
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(name) ; i++){
    char *tester[2] = {"a", "b"};
    if (strcmp(name[i],tester[i]) == 0){
        printf("letter is %s at \n", name[i]);
    }
}

}

main()
{
    printf("Hello World!! \n");
    char* myName[2] = {"a", "b"};
    printVowlOrElse(myName);

}
```

The output is:

```
Hello World!!
letter is a at
letter is b at
```

Which is correct since both arrays have the same thing, however I dont understand why it crashes. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know which introductory text you're following, but if it's telling you a bare `main()` is an acceptable signature for your main function, you need to ditch it right now.

Comment: Look at your array sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sizeof(name) does not return length of array, it returns size of pointer (for 32 bit 4 bytes). You should provide length of array to the function printVowlOrElse.

You can write printVowlOrElse as:

```
void printVowlOrElse(char *name[], int size)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        char *tester[2] = { "a", "b" };
        char result = compare_string(name[i], tester[i]);
        if (result == 0) {
            printf("letter is %s at \n", name[i]);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!! \n");
    char* myName[2] = { "a", "b" };
    printVowlOrElse(myName, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, I had no idea that sizeof was just a pointer. Thanks for pointing that out. Now it works well.

Comment: @JasonMarks, from your remark it is not clear if you really understood what is going on. In *this* case `sizeof` is only returning the size of a pointer, because `name` is not an array, it only looks as if it were. This is because it is a function parameter, where special rules apply. You should read on some information on arrays and pointers in C, e.g the C faq would be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is crashing because `printVowlOrElse` accepts a `char*` array of length 5, while you are only passing it a `char*` of length 2.

You iterate from 0 to `sizeof(name)`, which will return `sizeof(char**)`, and go out-of-bounds of the length 2 array you provide.

It's actually fairly dangerous because depending on your compiler, I think there's a potential to have a valid memory address floating around past the last element of your static array in `main`.  Since I debugged this using VC++ (yes, I cheated and used a C++ compiler), the debugging runtime memory marks all uninitialized stack memory with `0xCCCCCCCC`, which is an invalid read location, thus causing a crash.  Your memory values may differ.

Note that using `sizeof(name)` is also not sufficient.  `name` is an array of `char*`, thus a `char**`, and `sizeof` is going to return the size in number of bytes, not number of elements.  So, you get 4 since a pointer is 4 bytes when compiled for 32 bit architecture.  Use `sizeof(name) / (sizeof(char*))` instead.  Or, even more generically, `sizeof(name) / sizeof(name[0])`, once you know that `name[0]` is valid.

Comment: I just noticed that as you said it, so I changed the length from 5 to 2, but it still crashes. I  actually printed the length of name before making the change and saw it was 4, after I changed it i printed the length again and it still displays 4 as the length and it still crashes. Any ideas as to why the size of the array isnt changing?

Comment: @JasonMarks I've updated my answer to address your second issue.

Comment: -1 because your answer is simply wrong, @tyilmaz's is the correct one. `name` is actually a `char**` and `sizeof(name)` is the size of that pointer.

Comment: @JensGustedt Corrected.  "A simple mistake" as opposed to "simply wrong" in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

char *name[];    (to read it start with 'variable name' go to its right and then left, cover right again and then left, so on... untill you finish on it)

Thus it is read as " 'name' is an array of pointers to chars." so if you are doing sizeof(name), it returns the size of the array and hence, array length can be calculated by sizeof(name)/sizeof(name[0]);

```
#include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        char *name[5];          
        printf("%d\n", sizeof(*name));
        printf("%d\n", sizeof(name));
        return 0;       
    }

output as:
4
20
```

Explanation:

1) *name, refers to name[0] that is first element of array which is a pointer. 4 bytes in that case.

2) name, is actually an array of those many pointers as its elements. So, it returns size of array = 4*5 = 20 bytes

Now, if you have declaration as 
char (*name)[];

this will be read as " 'name' is a pointer to array of chars."
Thus, sizeof(name) will be 4 bytes. sizeof(*name) will give size of the array. Because *name refers to array of chars.

Hope this helps...